# How do I make a Maven module not export a jar?

Tags: maven-2

I have a Maven build with three modules.

- Module A exports a jar.
- Module B depends on A and exports a jar.
- Module C is a set of regression tests that depend on A and B.

The reason the regression tests aren't just part of module B is that they should be able to run against multiple versions of A and B to ensure backwards compatibility.  I want to be able to run `deploy` from the top level build to create A.jar and B.jar, but not C.jar.  Is this possible?

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to avoid maven-jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188746/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-maven-jar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<properties>
     <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

---

If you don't need to create a JAR at all, you might want to add two more properties:

```
<jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>
<maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
```

Note that you still need `maven.deploy.skip`, otherwise the build will fail during deployment.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding how to suppress the creation of the JAR, in case it is not needed.

Answer (score 6):

The maven deploy plugin includes a [skip](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html) options that prevents artifact deployment.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can try adding that to project C.

Answer (score 3):

Use below for module C:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Comment: I tried that.  Then I run mvn test from the top level, and C's tests don't run.

Comment: You may need to reorganize the heirarchy of your POM's. For example, you may need a super pom at the top and then C as a sub-module and then A and B as submodules under C.

Comment: If you choose packaging type of pom, you'll need to manually rebind all the usual plugins as per Pascal's answer below. You still want jar packaging for C, you just need to disable deployment for that module. sal has the right answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Use a packaging of type `pom` for C and rebind all required plugins:

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>process-test-resources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: While that probably works, it is rather verbose. Craig P. Motlin's answer provides a nicer solution.