# How do I build only one JAR file with classifier?

Tags: maven-2, maven-jar-plugin

I'm using `Maven 2` and `maven-jar-plugin` to build my `jar`.

I'd like to generate only a `jar` with a `classifier`. Is it possible?

In my example I'd like to generate only the `myjar-another-1.0.jar` but not `myjar-1.0.jar`.

After take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188746/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-maven-jar) I tried to skip the `default-jar`. But this seems to work only with version 3 of Maven (haven't tried thou.

The parent is to do the

```
<modules>
```

Thanks all!

Here is the relevant piece of my pom.xml:

Also tried in the global configuration segment.

```
<project>
         <!-- Definition of the Parent (only an aggregator) -->     
    <build>
      <plugins>
         <!-- <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId> -->
         <!-- surefire -->
         <!-- <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId> -->
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>another</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use it for the plugin element:

```
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>another</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Comment: Works for me. Not working how? Maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: In my example I'd like to generate only the `myjar-another-1.0.jar` but not `myjar-1.0.jar`.
What version?

Comment: I'm using maven v2.2.1. I've added the plugin as in my answer into one of my projects and it's produced for me only myproj-0.0.1-another.jar What are you getting?

Comment: I'm also getting the myjar-1.0.jar. It is possible to avoid it. @kan Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm not getting it, only the classified jar is generated. Maybe your pom has some other options, maybe it's influenced by something else. Publish here a minimal example which doesn't work for you.