# Skip default jar creation in maven causes error

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin

Im using maven 3.8.3. Tryig to avoid the step of the default jar creation, using the answers I found in topics like:

[remove jar created by default in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809559/remove-jar-created-by-default-in-maven)

[What is the best way to avoid maven-jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188746/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-maven-jar)

What I tried:

1.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

2. 

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
           <phase/>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

3. 

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>unwanted</finalName>
          <classifier>unwanted</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

4. I also checked the solution of `<packaging>pom</packaging>` instead of `jar`. but I'm not sure this is the use case.

More details: This is a non-empty module, containing resources and generated unversioned java sources.

Solutins #1-#3 caused me the following error:

```
The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact.
```

Please assist, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe what is the problem here and why do you need to prevent creating a jar file? If you have a module which contains generated java code this code must be compiled and in result must be packaged into a jar file..so this puzzles me even more?